# Starting an Activity when removing a fragment from the backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragmentmanager

In a point of my app I need to start an Activity when a fragment gets removed from the backstack.

So I'm listening the backstack changes with a `OnBackStackChangedListener` and when I detect the fragment is removed from the backstack I start the activity.

My problem is that some devices are reporting that, after starting the activity, the view of my activity becomes white (only showing the app's bar) and the fragment manager stops working (calls to replace or add new fragments shows nothing in the screen)

I could reproduce this error in a Samsung Galaxy 7 Edge. How can I fix that? I can avoid the error delaying the activity launch some millis with a handler but I see this as a dirty solution.

Thanks

Comment: you get any logcat warning/error ?

Comment: your code should accompany this question

Comment: No logcat messages. @Arunava Currently working in a simplified version in the code to post